# Interpreting regression results with decimal percentage variables

Tags: regression, interpretation, regression-coefficients

I have a regression where both my Y and X variables are measured in percent (so they are decimals values, mostly less than 0). The coefficient from the regression is 0.43. Is it correct to say that a 1 increase in X increases Y by 0.43, so when X increases by 100%, Y increases by 43%?

Comment: You mentioned 'mostly less than 0', meaning they are measuring percentage changes, right?

Comment: the dependent variable is abnormal returns (stocks) and the independent variable is earnings surprise, so I think neither are the percentage changes you may be thinking of

Comment: Standardized abnormal returns and standardized unexpected earnings? Following the wikipedia formulas?

Comment: Neither are standardized, the values are calculated from financial data

Answer (score 1):

> Is it correct to say that a 1 increase in X increases Y by 0.43, so when X increases by 100%, Y increases by 43%?

Yes, if you have a linear model, y = x*coef + intercept.